# Convert Local Time Zone to PST Time Zone in C#

Tags: c#, timezone

Let say my time zone in system right now is +5GMT

right now on my machine `01/14/2012 05:52PM` I want to convert it into PST time zone like

```
1/14/12 4:52:50 AM PST
```

and vice versa PST to GMT

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific SA Standard Time");

DateTime newDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(existingDateTime, timeZoneInfo);
```

You can see complete chart of available Time Zones [here](http://www.xiirus.net/articles/article-_net-convert-datetime-from-one-timezone-to-another-7e44y.aspx)

Also take a look at [Converting Between Any Two Time Zones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @HarisHasan's answer above, the following method will produce PST no matter where your code is running:

```
    public static DateTime GetPacificStandardTime()
    {
        var utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        TimeZoneInfo pacificZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
        var pacificTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc, pacificZone);
        return pacificTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific SA Standard Time");
```

Will fail if we deploy the application in Linux (In case of .NET Core), found this nice library which will give correct TimeZoneInfo in windows and Linux "TimeZoneConverter", using this we can convert like

```
using TimeZoneConverter;

TimeZoneInfo pst =TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Pacific Standard Time");
DateTime newDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(existingDateTime, pst);
```

Answer (score -3):

Below code convert to PST.

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
```